# How do I display/echo the data from an executed mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am attempting to understand how to prevent injections. Prior to this, I would structure my code as follows.

```
$empid = $_REQUEST['empid']
$query =("SELECT e.first AS first, e.last AS last, e.username AS uname FROM emps e WHERE e.id='$empid'"); 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);?>
```

Then to display the found username in my body, I would have.

```
<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);?>
<?php echo $row['uname'] ;?>
```

I am trying to accomplish this same thing with mysqli prepared statements. So far I have the following.

```
$query= $con->prepare("SELECT e.first AS first, e.last AS last, e.username AS uname FROM emps e WHERE e.id=?");
$query->bind_param("i", $empid);
$query->execute();
$query->close();
```

So I am pretty sure that the statement is set up correctly, but need to now echo the returned columns to the body on my webpage

Comment: the question is about echo not prepare. So there is an echo dupe target close. Please do some research :p

Comment: @Drew this link is of no help. it does not address the question

Comment: *So I am pretty sure that the statement is set up correctly, but need to now echo the returned columns to the body on my webpage* ... well the referenced target does show that. Thanks. Be well.

Comment: @craisondigital run a `fetch()` in a `while` loop but bind the results first. That's how you get to echo rows from a prepared statement.

Comment: @Drew *"well the referenced target does show that"* - OP here is wanting to echo rows from a prepared statement. The referenced target (answers) do not include a method for it; two different animals here and I have to lean on the OP's side here ;-) I feel the question should be reopened. Edit: *grazie!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:
add those rules after the execute.

```
$res = $query->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

and after that you can do what ur used to do with it, with the old way.

Comment: they're using mysqli_ here, not PDO as per the link you left http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php - Two different animals.

Comment: Thank You @Roy Stijsiger I will be testing this now.

Comment: @craisondigital I changed this reply

Comment: @Fred-ii- I changed it

Comment: However, `get_result()` may not be available for them to use on their system. I know that "I" can't use it on mine and need to bind the results instead and inside a loop. Just saying ;-)

Comment: Awesome !! this works PERFECT. Thank you @RoyStijsiger. Great Work!!

Comment: @craisondigital can u upvote it too:% looks ugly the minus 1 man

Comment: Done @RoyStijsiger

Answer (score 0):

A routine suggestion. Consider using PDO instead of mysqli. Just to show you the difference. Your code:

```
$query= $con->prepare("SELECT first, last, username AS uname FROM emps WHERE id=?");
$query->bind_param("i", $empid);
$query->execute();
$res = $query->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

PDO:

```
$query= $con->prepare("SELECT first, last, username AS uname FROM emps WHERE id=?");
$query->execute([$empid]);
$row = $query->fetch();
```

Almost two times shorter.

And keep in mind that `get_result` is not guaranteed to be available. It works all right on your local dev but check whether you have it on a production server.

While PDO doesn't have such a problem

Comment: Thank you @Your Common Sense. I've read about this, but your example makes it easy to understand. I will test this when I return.

Comment: I can't see an issue. try to var_dump $row may be. It's hard to tell just by looking.

Comment: yes, PDO is compatible with everything. Well FALSE means your query returned nothing.

Comment: I have got this working. I had to create a new pdo connection.  Also, I had to move the $query->close(); to the end of my page body after all results were displayed. If this looks correct, and you add them as a footnote to your answer above, i will mark this as an answer. Thanks so much for your time and your great guide [link](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)